# Is it possible to store MySQL data as comressed?

Tags: mysql, database, compression, gzip

Is it possible to store MySQL data compressed? Option for that in MySQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [compressed table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/compressed-format.html), or ([de](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/encryption-functions.html#function_uncompress))[compress](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/encryption-functions.html#function_compress) data stored in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use the [archive storage engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/archive-storage-engine.html)